# Approximated number of elastic in a box is 100 with 1 significant figure. How to express this in $x \pm y$ notation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, significant-figures, rounding-unit

Question from stackexchange
[How many significant figures are there after 96
is correct to 1 significant figure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410726/how-many-significant-figures-are-there-after-96-is-correct-to-1-significant)

From this statement:

> It is given that the approximated number of elastic in a box is 100.
> If the number is correct to 1
>
> significant figure, what is the smallest possible number of elastic?
>
> Answer: 100

How would one express this in $x \pm y$ notation?:

All x in 100 <= x <= 149 gets mapped to $1 \times 10^2$ = 100.

How to express this in $x \pm y$ notation?

I would have supposed $100 \pm 49$, because 51..149 gets rounded to 100,
but then the statement from the correct answer will be violated:
"smallest possible number is 100".

Answer (score 0):

Significant "numbers" is not significant "figures"!  In any case, "96 correct to 1 significant figure" means that it has been rounded to the "ones" place.  And that means the number can be anywhere from 95.5 to 96.5.  [tex]x= 96\pm 0.5[/tex].

Comment: Corrected number into figure. Thx.
Did you not actually mean to the tens place?
Actually my question focuses to the citation part.
The "what happens to  96" was answered as: It gets rounded to 100 and has 2 sig figs. Because the tens place overflows to the hundreds place.